# Customize Tab Bar in AppDelegate iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to customize the `Tab Bar` in the `AppDelegate.m`. I found code online to declare the `Tab Bar` like this:

```
// Assign tab bar item with titles

UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

This makes sense if the Tab bar is the root view controller, but it isn't. I get a crash because an `Unrecognized selector sent to instance...` This makes sense, because the tab bar isnt loaded until I pass the Login View Controller.

How can I style the tab bar in the AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

If Login View Controller is the `rootViewController`, this gives full reason to configure the `UITabBarController` inside the Login View Controller before you present it.

Comment: How can I reference the Tab Bar Controller from the LoginViewController?

Comment: How is your app structured? Storyboards? Tell me your viewcontroller hierarchy :)